# Linear Algebra: Network Flow problem

Tags: linear-algebra, network-flow

So I have the following problem:

[image]

And I have obtained the following system of equations:
$$\begin{align*}
-x_1+x_2&=400\\
x_1+x_3-x_4&=600\\
x_2+x_3+x_5&=300\\
x_4+x_5&=100
\end{align*}$$

By using the Gaussian elimination method, I found the following system of equations (using rref() on a TI83):

$$\begin{align*}
x_1+x_3+x_5&=0\\
x_2+x_3+x_5&=0\\
x_4+x_5&=1\\
0&=1
\end{align*}$$

I would like some clarification as to what I am doing wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: The total coming into any particular node must equal the total coming out. On the top left node, you have $400+x_2$ coming in, and $x_1$ coming out, so the equation should be $x_1 = 400+x_2$, or $x_1-x_2=400$; you've got the left hand side multiplied by $-1$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first balanced flow equation is incorrect, it should be: $$x_1 - x_2 = 400$$